# Join 2 Select Queries in a Same Table in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, new-operator

I have a Table Name Called tbl_events and it does have following columns

Id,Event_Name, District,Branch_Type,Points

I need a Sum of Points Column Where Branch_Type=2; and Sum of Points Divided by 10 Where Branch_Type=2 after that I have to Add those Two Values And Group that Result by District and Order by Desc. I tried this Query but Seems to something wrong Can anyone help, please?

```
Select (t1.B_Points + t2.D_Points) as T_Points,District From 
(Select Sum(Points)*.1 as B_Points ,District From tblstudents Where Branch_Type=3 group by District)t1
Left Join(Select Sum(Points) as D_points, District From tblstudents Where Branch_Type=2 group by District)t2 on 
(t1.District=t2.District) Order by Desc
```

Comment: can you please sample data and your expected output

Comment: Expected out put will be Points Should be group by District name in Descending Order 
District            |     Points   
Kandy             |      550
Colombo         |      450
Matale             |      350

Answer (score 0):

You need to add column alias `T_Points` in order by

```
Select (t1.B_Points + t2.D_Points) as T_Points,District 
From 
(
  Select Sum(Points)*.1 as B_Points ,District From tblstudents 
  Where Branch_Type=3 group by District
)t1
Left Join
(
  Select Sum(Points) as D_points, District From tblstudents 
  Where Branch_Type=2 group by District
)t2 on t1.District=t2.District
 Order by T_Points Desc
```

Comment: This Query Throws this Error 
Error
SQL query: Documentation


Select (t1.B_Points + t2.D_Points) as T_Points, District 
From 
(
  Select Sum(Points)*.1 as B_Points ,District From tblstudents 
  Where Branch_Type=3 group by District
)t1
Left Join
(
  Select Sum(Points) as D_points, District From tblstudents 
  Where Branch_Type=2 group by District
)t2 on t1.District=t2.District
 Order by T_Points Desc LIMIT 0, 25
MySQL said: Documentation

#1052 - Column 'District' in field list is ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

You seem to just want conditional aggregation:

```
select district,
       sum(case when branch_type = 3 then 0.1 * points
                when branch_type = 2 then points
                else 0
           end) as t_points
from tblstudents
group by district;
```

If you want to order by the points descending, then add:

```
order by t_points desc
```

Note:  This assumes that you want districts that have neither branch type.  If that is not an issue, move the logic to the `where` clause:

```
select district,
       sum(points * (case when branch_type = 3 then 0.1 else 1.0 end) as t_points
from tblstudents
where branch_type in (2, 3)
group by district
order by t_points desc;
```

Comment: select district, sum(case when branch_type in (2, 3) then points else 0 end) as t_points from tblstudents group by district order by t_points desc 

This Query is giving a result that points group by district but the Problem is I want the Points to be Divided by 10 when branch_type = 3, and Add that calculated points with the Points with branch_type=2 as a total points something like simply mentioned below in two Queries 

(Select District, Sum(Points)/(10) From tblstudents Where branch_type = 3) + 
(Select District, Sum(Points) From tblstudents Where branch_type=2) Group by District

Comment: I got it Actually I need this Solution which derived from your example Thank you Very Much 

select district, sum(case when branch_type in (3) then points * .1 else points end) as t_points from tblstudents group by district order by t_points desc